# filtering data to an exact match React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently mapping through an array of 100 objects that look like the following  `{id: 1, name: 'User 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'User 2' ... all the way up to 100}` and I am displaying them in `jsx`.  I am then filtering through the results using an input field and checking to see if the `formData` from the `input` matches the items within my array and am returning possible matches of Users. The problem is when I search for ex: `er 2` in my input; however, it will return every user with a 2 in their name like so: User 2, User 20, User 21, all the way up to 29. I would like my filter to be more strict. If I search: er 2, I would like only User 2 to come up.  I am unsure of how to make my filtered results more explicit.  My code is as follows.

here is the react module that generates the array of 100 users

```
export function getUsers(n) {
  const users = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    users.push({ id: i, name: `User ${i}` })
  }
  return users
}
```

here is the component I am displaying my data and filtering through it using the input

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from './Data'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  people: ''
}

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(getUsers(100))

  const handleInputChange = field => e => {
    console.log(field + ' ' + e.currentTarget.value)
    setFormData({ ...formData, [field]: e.currentTarget.value })
  }

  const deletePerson = peep => {
    const deletePerson = person.filter(n => n !== peep)
    setPerson(deletePerson)
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <input
        id='people'
        name='people'
        onChange={handleInputChange('people')}
        value={formData.people}
        InputProps={{
          disableUnderline: true
        }}
      />
      {person
        .filter(person => {
          if (formData.people === '') return true
          return person.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(formData.people.toLowerCase())
        })
        .map(peep => {
          return (
            <>
              <div>{peep.name}</div>
              <button onClick={() => deletePerson(peep)}>delete me</button>
            </>
          )
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated and further help me in my overall understanding of javascript and react.

Comment: the input is provided in the example.  when you're asking what my input is like what exactly do you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
  {person
    .filter(person => {
      if (formData.people === '') return true
      const escaped = escapeRegExp(formData.people);
      const re = new RegExp(`.*${escaped}$`);
      return re.test(person.name);
    })
...

function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); 
}
```

However, I think that you may be making a mistake making the test stricter in this way. Most users won't expect a search to match the end of a string, which is what you seem to want, not an "exact" match per the question title.

Comment: is this only accounting for matches at the end of the string?  could you by chance show me how I could incorporate the reg exp into the code block provided.

Comment: You said you want `er2`  to match User2 but not User20? How do you distinguish those except by the 2 ending the string? You need to be precise.

Comment: I was just curious as to what the regEx was taking into account to distinguish each filtered result from each other.  Makes sense

Comment: By the way instead of the $ sign in the regex (end of string), you could use \b. That matches a word break, which includes the end of a string.

Comment: is there a way to possibly stack the old filter with the regEx you provided as well.

Comment: @RobTerrell there's no need. A regex can do everything that `includes` can do, plus a lot more. It seems you're a little bit unclear about what you want the filter to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach if you want to avoid using regex for performance reasons
Note that this approach works only if your input is unique `er n`

```
.filter(person => {
          if (formData.people === '') return true
          str = person.name
            n = str.slice(2,str.length )
           if(n==input) return person
        })
```

However if your input is not unique you can use a regex pattern to detect the UserId in the input

```js
const users = []
 function getUsers(n) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    users.push({ id: i, name: `User ${i}` })
  }
  return users
}
getUsers(100)


input="use er100ers"
x=users.filter(person => {
  if (input === '') return true
    const str = person.name
    const n = str.slice(5,str.length )
    const inpid = input.match(/(\d+)/)
   if(n==inpid[0]) return person
})
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Performance is not a reason to avoid regex. They are extremely fast.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I never said that regex are slow, all what I meant is the string operations are definitely faster than regular expressions, and most of the time regex are used for performing complicated operations, and in my own humble opinion  I don't think they are necessary in this situation, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Speed is just not a reason for choosing one approach over the other, since the difference will not matter at all for such a trivial operation. But apart from that, your solution does not work. `str` and `n` are not declared for starters. And what your logic does is check if the substring of the name starting from index 2 matches the filter input. That's not what the OP wants, and will crash if the string length is less than 3.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote!! and with all respect this solution works, and it serves exactly what OP wants you can test it, or prove me wrong i would like to learn from my mistakes

Comment: I don't like to downvote, but honestly this solution does not work at all. str and n are not defined and will immediately produce a syntax error. You use the variable input which is also not defined, while using formData.people previously. You return true at the second line (a boolean) but 'person' (a string) at the fifth line, which will work with a filter, but is inconsistent and technically incorrect. And finally, if you correct the syntax errors, the logic is poor anyway.

Comment: ...Sure it works if the strings look like 'User2', 'User3' etc, but what if the user names change slightly? What if the input is 'ser2' instead of 'er2' ? You should always aim for robust code that provides a general solution, not code that only works in a very specific arbitrary case.

Comment: My solution is specifically tailored to answer OP's question, he explicitly mentioned what the input looks like "er 2", however if the input can be something different than that, it should have been already clarified in the question. It's not necessary in javascript to define a variable, I agree it's a bad feature in the language, and should be avoided. However, my intension is to show an alternative solution, person is not  a string is the **object** passed from the array

Comment: I have added a solution to the situation where the input can't be predictable, I hope you check it out and tell me if it's a better solution, and all in all i won't downvote a solution just because I disagree with it, and I think your solution is good and it deserves an upvote

Comment: Honestly I find it hard to believe you're defending a solution that works for only one input and one set of names. That's a valid reason for a downvote. Please listen to feedback from an experienced developer rather than getting defensive. WRT your new solution, it suffers the same problem of being far too specific and therefore fragile, but I think this discussion is no longer productive.

Comment: I haven't been defensive, I upvoted your answer, and asked for your feedback regarding my second solution, there is no shame in learning from mistakes, I was explaining to you why I consider the first solution as correct, i asked OP before writing my answer on what the input is like, and he explicitly said it's the one in the question,

Comment: My final remark: "fragile" means it breaks easily, in this case because you hard-code the value 5 into string.slice and then look for a number, but what if the OP decides he wants to have a different set of user names, or the user names are unknown because they come from a server - almost certainly the case in real life. The likely real use case is finding a user name that matches some string the user input where that string is anything and the user names are anything.

Comment: I am not sure how you criticise both of my solutions when your own code has the problems you mentioned, your code won't work, it will break if the input is `er2`,not `er 2 ` or if the User is slightly different, on top of that your code is very very slow comparing to both of my solutions, and yet you called them poor and fragile, i didn't even have to use regular expressions because it is an overkill in this situation and if you ask any experienced developer they will always advice in finding an alternative solution to using regex, they are not a good choice especially when used in a loop,